# Access simple node.js app subdirs with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, url, nginx, node.js, folder-redirection

I have a Ubuntu server with nginx installed on it and run a simple node.js app on port 3000.

I managed to configure nginx to serve me the app on /.

My structure looks like this:

```
mainFolder
  app.js etc...
  ------------->folder1
                  index.html
                  ----------->folder2
                                index.html
```

Now when accessing my servers IP in browser i get the `index.html` from folder1: this is correct.

But when i try to access `myIp/folder2/index.html`  I get :
404 Not Found

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here pls?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the file tree you provided, I understand `folder2`is located in `folder1`. That means to acces `folder2/index.html`, the full URL you should use is: `127.0.0.1/folder1/folder2/index.html` replacing the IP by whatever is your IP/domain name.

If you want to access it with `127.0.0.1/folder2/index.html` you need to put `folder2`in the same folder as `folder1`.

Comment: Thy for your answer but I just managed to get it work. I just commented out:  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;